# open() system call header file requirements

Tags: c, header-files, system-calls, manpage

I am using x86_64 GNU/Linux with gcc.
SYNOPSIS section of `man -s2 open` says:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int open(const char *pathname, int flags);
int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
int creat(const char *pathname, mode_t mode);
```

Now when I try to compile the following code snippet, `gcc` doesn't throw a warning/error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int fd;

    fd = open("foo.txt", O_RDWR, 0777);
    if(fd == -1)
        perror("open");

    fd = creat("foo.txt", 0777);
    if(fd == -1)
        perror("creat");

    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

So are `types.h` and `stat.h` optional? What purpose do they serve in manpage of `open()`?

Comment: Check `fcntl.h` -- I assume it's including `types.h` and `stat.h`

Comment: It includes `<bits/types.h>` and `<bits/stat.h>`. But I still don't understand why `<sys/types.h>` and `<sys/stat.h>` are there in `man -s2 open`.

Comment: Since you didn't state, did you compile with `-Wall`? If not, do so and check then for warnings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The man page serves as an instruction both to programmers and to compiler manufacturers.

It is possible that you don't *need* to include them *on your system*. However, the man page describes a portable way to use the methods, so you should include them anyway.

Comment: Can't argue, can't verify if the need for `<sys/types.h>` and `<sys/stat.h>` varies from system to system as I don't have another system to test. Can you give any one example of system needing these headers explicitly as I don't want to leave this to _may be possible_, _may be not_

Comment: @rootkea: Generally, things *do* vary. As KlasLindbäck said, the manpage specifies how to do it *portably*, and you should stick to it (because after all, it doesn't cost anything to have those extra includes if not needed; but your code won't compile, or worse, will invoke UB, if they *are* needed and you didn't include).